# Windows 7 Cannot connect to network - first try only

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

On my windows 7 machine, when I try to connect to a wireless network, it always fails instantly with a "windows was unable to connect to this network" message. I click cancel, then try again, and it connects just fine. This happens at home and at the university. Any ideas as to what causes this problem, and how to remedy it?

Comment: Is this after a resume from standby or hibernate?, or dies it do it from a cold boot also?

Comment: Does the event log give you more information?

Comment: Are you sure that when you try to connect to the network the first time, that both the network and computer are ready? (Eg, that they are not still booting up?)